# Apache shutdown unexpectedly httpd.conf problem

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

I have xampp installed on windows 10 it was working perfect until yesterday , and my problem doesn't related with "port" it's about httpd.conf 
can anyone please share httpd.conf from xampp 3.2.2

```
C:\xampp\apache\bin> .\httpd.exe
    AH00526: Syntax error on line 168 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
    Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

````
8:29:28 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
8:29:28 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
8:29:28 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
8:29:28 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
8:29:28 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
8:29:28 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is the use of "order" in line 168 in httpd.conf file. are you using "order allow, deny"? it dont work in newer editions. try changing it to "Require all granted"

AllowOverwrite All
Require all granted

and nothing else